# Is there a better way to detab (expand tabs) using Perl?

Tags: perl

I wanted to detab my source files.  (Please, no flame about WHY I wanted to detab my sources. That's not the point :-) I couldn't find a utility to do that.  Eclipse didn't do it for me, so I implemented my own.

I couldn't fit it into a one liner (-e) program.
I came with the following, which did the job just fine.

```
while( <> )
{
    while( /\t/ ) {
        s/^(([^\t]{4})*)\t/$1    /;
        s/^((([^\t]{4})*)[^\t]{1})\t/$1   /;
        s/^((([^\t]{4})*)[^\t]{2})\t/$1  /;
        s/^((([^\t]{4})*)[^\t]{3})\t/$1 /;
    }
    print;
}
```

However, it makes me wonder if Perl - the champion language of processing text - is the right tool. The code doesn't seem very elegant. If I had to detab source that assume tab=8 spaces, the code would look even worse.

Specifically because I can think of a deterministic state machine with only 4 states to do the job.

I have a feeling that a more elegant solution exists. Am I missing a Perl idiom? In the spirit of TIMTOWTDI I'm curious about the other ways to do it.

u.

Comment: Removing tabs isn't *quite* as easy as it might seem. Mixed tab/space indentation may end up breaking. Similarly, it's quite easy to hide a space in a tab: "\t \t" will actually be displayed as two tabs (i.e. typically 4, 8 or 16 columns).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I remember a detabify script from one of the O'Reilly books, but I can't seem to find a link now.

I have had to solve this problem as well, and I settled on this concise solution to detabify a line:

```
1 while $line =~ s/\t/" " x ($tablength - ($-[0] % $tablength))/e ;
```

In this regular expression `$-[0]` is the length of the "pre-matched" portion of the line --  the number of characters before the tab character.

---

As a one-liner:

```
perl -pe '1 while s/\t/" "x(4-($-[0]%4))/e' input
```

Comment: Nice, I wasn't familiar with the @+ and @- arrays. Thanks. However, your answer if off by one. The correct answer is: 
    while s/\t/ " " x ( 4 - ($-[0]%4) ) / e

Comment: Thanks Uri, that was a good catch. Maybe I should have tried harder to use an existing module.

Answer (score 12):

What ever happened to the old Unix program "expand"?  I used to use that all the time.

Comment: +1 I'm not sure if the question was rhetorical, but on my Debian/Ubuntu systems it's in the 'coreutils' package.

Comment: I found "expand" works great.  Here is an example of how to use it to expand 4-character tabs to spaces:  `expand --tabs=4 input.cpp > output.cpp`

Answer (score 7):

Whenever I want to expand tabs, I use [Text::Tabs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Tabs.html).

Answer (score 6):

This can be easily done in vim:

```
:set expandtab
:retab
```

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces

Answer (score 3):

Can't let `vi` be all alone here. Emacs:

```
M-x tabify
M-x untabify
```

Answer (score 2):

I do this in vim with:

```
:%s/^V^I/    /g
```

(That's a literal <kbd>^V</kbd> followed by a literal <kbd>tab</kbd>), and then `:%gq` to fix incorrect spacing. Perl is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

The exact expression is:

```
1 while $line =~ s/\t/" " x ($tablength+1 - ($-[0] % $tablength))/e ;
```

And expand is useful for command line not inside a program which may expand or not some lines.