# Removing tab character - perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using the following perl expression to remove tabs from [here](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.macperl.anyperl/154)

```
$text =~ s{(.*?)\t}{$1.(' ' x ($g_tab_width - length($1) % $g_tab_width))}ge;
```

I've simplified my understanding and translation down to the following (assuming a tab width of four spaces)

```
$text =~  s/(.*?)\t/'    '/;
```

but I feel like I've broken Einstein's instruction

> Make things as simple as possible, but not simpler.

I'm testing with the following input strings.

```
"\t \t"
"\t\t \t"
"\t\t \t\t \t"
"\t\t \t\t     \t"
```

Can someone demonstrate an input string that would give inconsistent results between these two? (within the problem space of removing tabs)

Comment: Since the second one doesn't reference `$1` in the replacement it won't work... unless that's just a typo?

Comment: You misunderstand tabs.  Tabs represent a variable number of spaces, not a constant number of them.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like [perltidy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perltidy)?

Comment: Thanks @TLP - I was actually trying to port some perl code to java code, and wanted to make sure I understood it first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to detab (expand tabs) using Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952645/is-there-a-better-way-to-detab-expand-tabs-using-perl)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that your second simplified expression is supposed to be:

```
$text =~ s/(.*?)\t/$1    /g;
# four spaces -------^^^^
```

and that `$g_tab_width` is four; nothing else would make sense to me here so I'll live dangerously and assume that things are supposed to make sense.

Given that, almost anything with tabs will produce different results. For example:

```
"where\tis pancakes house?"
```

Produces these results:

```
"Where   is pancakes house?"   # Long method.
"Where    is pancakes house?"  # Simplified method.
```

Live version: http://ideone.com/LbnNx

The only time they'll both produce the same result is when your non-tab components are all 4*n characters long, for example:

```
"xxxx\tyyyy\tzzzz"
```

Live version: http://ideone.com/Kvp3l

Comment: Is there a reason why `$text =~ s/\t/    /g;` (with 4 spaces, of course) wouldn't work? Are you trying to preserve any tab characters, or just replace them all?

Comment: @Sho: Because he's trying to `$text =~ s{(.*?)\t}{$1.(' ' x ($g_tab_width - length($1) % $g_tab_width))}ge;` so the spaces per-tab depend on where the tab is.